# How can I append an new Element to an Array in the Userdefaults (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui, userdefaults

I wanna have an String Array in the Userdefaults, which I can edit. That means I want to append new Items to this Array.Here is some example Code

```
var defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.array(forKey: "myArray")?.append("NewElement")
```

But I get this Error Code:

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value

How can I handle that? Do you need more information? Thanks for your time
Boothosh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the result of the function to variable before you can modify it

```
if var array = defaults.array(forKey: "myArray") {
     array.append("NewElement")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save or read an array, but you should make your job finish before saving it, and then you can start using or adding new data after reading.

*PS: I used SwiftUI for show case, but **saveData()** and **readData()** functions are usable in UIKit as well.*

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            
            Button("saveData") { saveData() }
            
            Button("readData") { readData() }

        }
        .font(Font.body.weight(Font.Weight.bold))

    }
    
}
```

---

```
func saveData() {
    
    var array: [String] = [String]()
    
    array.append("a")
    array.append("b")
    array.append("c")
    
    UserDefaults.standard.set(array, forKey: "array")
    
    print("saved!")
    
}
```

---

```
func readData() {
    
    if let unwrappedData = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "array") {
        
        var array: [String] = unwrappedData
        
        array.append("d")
        
        print(array)
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `UserDefaults` has a specific method to retrieve array of strings called `stringArray(forKey:)`. There is no need to map the elements from `Any` to `String`

Comment: `if var array = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "array") {`

Comment: Btw casting would work as well `array(forKey: "array") as? [String]`

Comment: No need to create another object. You can simply use `if var` instead of `if let`. Check my second comment

Comment: yes, I wanted keep **if let** rule untouched. but totally agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend UserDefaults and create a computed property with a getter and a setter. This way you can directly access your array straight from disk:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    var myStringArray: [String] {
        get { stringArray(forKey: "myStringArray") ?? [] }
        set { set(newValue, forKey: "myStringArray") }
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
UserDefaults.standard.myStringArray.append("NewElement")
UserDefaults.standard.myStringArray  // ["NewElement"]
```